# Loading a neural network (.nnet) file in java

Tags: java, neural-network

I am working on a project that requires a neural network. I used Neuroph Studio to create the model and train it. On loading the file in java, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1659)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.readObject(NeuralNetwork.java:688)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.createFromFile(NeuralNetwork.java:707)
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.createFromFile(NeuralNetwork.java:728)
    at DMK.Predictor.main(Predictor.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 40 more
Java Result: 1
```

I am not very good in java and I don't know what to do. 
This is the code in the main class

```
String rootPath="/Users/Dennis/Documents/neuroph/Crime Predictor/Neural Networks/"; 
        NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile(rootPath+"predictor1.nnet");
        //set the input 
        neuralNetwork.setInput(0.5, 0.3, 0.47, 0.12, 0.86, 0.59, 0.96, 0.74);
        //calculate the result using nnet
        neuralNetwork.calculate();
        double[] networkOutput = neuralNetwork.getOutput();
```

Please assist.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger` - make sure your `.classpath` is configured properly.

Comment: How do I do that? If its the one you set in the environment variables, I've already done that